# Downgrade npm to an older version

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, downgrade

I tried updating `npm` to see if it would solve some dependency problems we were having, and now I want to downgrade to the version the rest of the development team is using. How can I install an older version?

I updated `npm` according to the instructions on the [About `npm` CLI versions](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm-versions):

> ### The latest release of `npm`
>
> The latest release of `npm` is the most recent stable version. When you install Node.js, `npm` is automatically installed. However, `npm` is released more frequently than Node.js, so to install the latest stable version of `npm`, on the command line, run:
>
> `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: I suggest that you downgrade or update the node version, then the npm version should follow.
You can do something like this :   nvm use v16.16.0 it would then show version 8.11.0 for the npm and version 16.16.0 for the node

Answer (score 550, accepted):

Just replace `@latest` with the version number you want to downgrade to. I wanted to downgrade to version 3.10.10, so I used this command:

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

If you're not sure which version you should use, look at the [version history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm?activeTab=versions). For example, you can see that 3.10.10 is the latest version of npm 3.

Comment: What does `-g` mean in this case? Can you have a repo-specific version of npm?

Comment: You can install `npm` in your repo, @JimAho, but you get a warning, and I couldn't figure out how to run the local version. Seems best to avoid this situation, I guess.

Comment: g stands for global

Comment: FYI: Make sure you do this from a cmd that has admin priv.

Comment: Any idea on how to downgrade npm when a non-compatible Node version is installed? For example, Node is v8 and npm v7. It looks like Node 8 doesn't work fine with npm, so npm complaints about it and it doesn't let you downgrade to the compatible npm v6.

Comment: For some Angular packages, I needed to downgrade npm to `^7.5.6`. `npm install -g npm@7` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: but npm -v still prints the latest version

Comment: If you do get an error, you may want to sanity check your directory ownership by running the same command, but with `sudo`

Comment: I get an error of:  `ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '~/.asdf/installs/nodejs/16.13.2/.npm/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '~/.asdf/installs/nodejs/16.13.2/.npm/lib/node_modules/.npm-75DsjTB1'` maybe because I'm using asdf version manager? But then if I get rid of my npm directory how will npm be able to install npm ? Might try rolling back my node version and hoping that works 

Comment: It is not working... still

Answer (score 68):

Just need to add version of which you want

> upgrade or downgrade

```
npm install -g npm@version
```

**Example** if you want to downgrade from npm 5.6.0 to 4.6.1 then,

```
npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

It is tested on linux

Answer (score 33):

```
npm install -g npm@4
```

This will install the latest version on the major release 4, so no need to specify version number. Replace 4 with whatever major release you want.

Answer (score 5):

Even I run `npm install -g npm@4`, it is not ok for me.

Finally, I download and install the old node.js version.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v7.10.1/

It is npm version 4.

You can choose any version here
https://nodejs.org/download/release/

Comment: You can find the node.js with a specific version of npm by searching in [Looking for latest release of a version branch?](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/#looking-for-latest-release-of-a-version-branch).

Comment: This is the correct answer, npm is tied to the node version

Comment: Soooo...you download the older version then you delete the newer? what are the next steps to actually running the app?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the same error as when trying to use `npm` to install the older version: `ERROR: npm v9.1.1 is known not to run...`

Answer (score 1):

For windows, you need to delete `npm*` folder in `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm*` . Uninstall `node` js and reinstall them again with its compatible `npm` version.

Answer (score 0):

NVM (Node Version Manager) is also an option. Installation is [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases).

We can downgrade/upgrade node versions on the fly by using this tool.

Usage:

```
nvm -v
nvm install vX.Y.Z
nvm ls
nvm list available
nvm use X.Y.Z
```