# Package-lock.json being built with weird structure and doubled in size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

Hey When I am running npm install and my package lock file is being generated it is building the file in a weird structure. Now I have checked with our other developers to try and simulate this on the same branches and they don't get the same issues. So this must be a problem local to me.

I did recently update node however I am running the same node version as the other devs and they don't get the issue.

node version - 14.17.3
npm version - 7.20.1

I thought it could be a node issue at first but we are on the same version. I have tried removing node_modules and the json lock and performing a new npm i but get the same issue.

When running npm run bundle it seems to build ok but the file structure looks strange to me and it has doubled in line size. I cant put the entire contents of the file here as its over 50,000 lines long. But i can give you a snapshot of how the file starts from how it should look to how it is now.

[image]

Before:

```
  {
  "name": "@culture-trip/header-ui-module",
  "version": "8.12.11",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/code-frame": {
      "version": "7.12.13",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.12.13.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-HV1Cm0Q3ZrpCR93tkWOYiuYIgLxZXZFVG2VgK+MBWjUqZTundupbfx2aXarXuw5Ko5aMcjtJgbSs4vUGBS5v6g==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@babel/highlight": "^7.12.13"
      }
    },
    "@babel/compat-data": {
      "version": "7.13.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/compat-data/-/compat-data-7.13.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-EaI33z19T4qN3xLXsGf48M2cDqa6ei9tPZlfLdb2HC+e/cFtREiRd8hdSqDbwdLB0/+gLwqJmCYASH0z2bUdog==",
      "dev": true
    },
```

After:

```
{
  "name": "@culture-trip/header-ui-module",
  "version": "8.12.11",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "@culture-trip/header-ui-module",
      "version": "8.12.11",
      "license": "TCT",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
        "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
        "react-autocomplete": "github:culture-trip/react-autocomplete#415ebd07c1b5a9037513a76d82d6e0fa54b7fc50",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
      },
```

As you can see the actual structure has changed. Im really not sure whats going on here so hopping someone can help.

Answer (score 6):

Your `package-lock.json` file is using `lockfileVersion: 2` it has likely changed since you updated from an older `npm` version.

```json
"lockfileVersion": 2,
```

The new file is flattened to increase performance when reading and writing. this inadvertently makes the file much longer.

If you want to continue using the old version of `lockfile` you could [downgrade your npm version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415343/downgrade-npm-to-an-older-version) to anything below 7.

[More on the package-lock.json file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json)

Edit: You don't have to downgrade `npm` see Vadim's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to downgrade your npm, you can keep the old `package-lock.json` format by using the `--lockfile-version` flag

In your case

```
npm i --lockfile-version 1
```

will work.